# How to download a list of objects as an Excel file?

Tags: java, jsp

I am displaying a list of objects in a webpage in table format using JSP. The webpage includes filter option to filter the rows. The rows getting displayed should be available for the user to download as an excel file.

How to convert a list of objects to excel file?

Comment: You make the link point to a servlet. This servlet loads the data to export, uses Apache POI (for example) to generate an Excel document containing this data, sets the content type header of the response to the appropriate content type, and then writes the generated bytes to the servlet output stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to develop a web app then you can simply write your own csv method in your model/pojo class i.e. Contact.java

```
 public String toCsv() {
     return id + ","+ firstName + "," + lastName + "," + email + "," +    contactNo + "," + addedDate + "," + modifiedDate + "," + status + "\r\n";
 }
```

then you can call this method to download all the csv list file

```
 private void download(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    response.setHeader("Content-type","text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.csv");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires"," 0");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    // contactDAO.getAll() being the list
    for(Contact c: contactDAO.getAll()){
        out.println(c.toCsv());
    }
}
```